# How to handle data or char -1 when reading from file, since EOF is also -1

Tags: c

I'm trying to read series of negative numbers from a file.
Number -1 is repeated n number of times, and I also read all data till EOF.
since data is -1 and EOF is also -1, how to handle this situation?

Comment: We'll need code, but my guess is that you fail to use `int`. The value of `EOF` is `int (-1)`, which is distinct from values `0..UCHAR_MAX`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Functions returning EOF do not return other signed integers, so there's your problem.

Comment: The value you store in a variable passed as an argument to a function like fscanf should be different from the one you use to store its return value, so I don't get what is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The standard C character input functions return a value that is either an `unsigned char` or `EOF`. Thus, to use the return value from a function like `fgetc`, store it in an `int`, not `char`:

```
int x = fgetc(stdin);
if (x == EOF)
    // Code for handling error or end of file.
else
    // Code for handling a character.
```

Also note that many of the standard C routines for working with characters use `unsigned char`. Using `char` in your code can cause problems.

If your code has a function that reads text from the input and converts numerals in it to numbers and then returns those numbers, you must design your function so that it has some way of indicating whether it is returning −1 or `EOF`. A common way to do this is to return two separate values: One is an indication of whether a value was successfully read or not, and the other is the value (if successful).

Methods of returning two values include:

- Return a struct that contains two members.
- Return a status indication (success or failure) in the function return value and return the actual value in an object that is passed to the function via a pointer.

Source: C 2018 7.21.7.1 paragraphs 2 and 3 say:

> If the end-of-file indicator for the input `stream` pointed to by stream is not set and a next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`…
>
> If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`. Otherwise, the `fgetc` function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by `stream`. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`.